# psexec fails with error Could not start PsExec service on NTDB2UT02:

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, psexec

We recently moved from a Windows 2003 server to Windows 2008 R2 server and now I see that all my psexec jobs fail.

thsi is how they are coded to run:

c:\shell\psexec.exe \NTDB2UT02 -u conseco\plat -i cmd.exe

I then get prompted for a password and as soon as I enter the password I get the error message below

PsExec v1.31 - execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2002 Mark Russinovich
www.sysinternals.com

Password:
Could not start PsExec service on NTDB2UT02:
The system cannot find the file specified.

So I went back to the Windows 2003 server that we were using earlier and I know it worked there because I have proof that it ran, and now I get the same message from the old Windows 2003 server too.

I read on a few posts that I could use the cmdkey to add a cached credential and I even tried doing that on both servers, but it didnt help at all.

I am going to try using a newer version of psexec, but I doubt that this will change anything at all.

Any tips or if anyone has successfully figured out a solution to this (or even a workaround), sharing that will be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this on 2003 server and found that when I turned off firewall everything worked, then when turning firewall back on it didn't.  I found the problem under firewall exceptions "File and Printer Sharing".  When you go to edit the service, there are 4 entries, and when you check the scope they are set for your network subnet only.  My problem was/is that we use multiple subnets and this machine did not match to the other machines trying to access it.  If you find this is also your problem, and not the admin$ share issue (you can search against that), update the network subnets in a custom list (or if you're daring to attacks, allow any computer - bad idea).  You only need to update ports 139 and 445  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Carlo - thanks for the comment, but we don't have any firewalls turned on. how do I make sure that the admin$ share is accessible? whats the best way to check and make sure?>

Comment: @user811433 Run `\\COMPUTERNAME\C$`

Comment: we can access \\computer\c$...it just doesn't work with psexec